# What is a good place to have a bird's eye view of Boston?

Tags: vantage-points, photography, boston

I'm looking for a place to take pictures of Boston, esp. **Back Bay's brownstones**. What is a good place to have a bird's eye view of Boston? Some place free and open to tourists would be great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A great place to have a bird's eye view of Boston is the Skywalk Observatory.  It is located at the top of the Prudential Center.  Please find the link below:

http://www.prudentialcenter.com/shop/shop_detail.php?id=64

It is not free but it isn't too expensive and open to the public

Ticket Prices:
Adults **$19.00**
Seniors **$15.00**
Children under 12 **$13.00**
Student with college ID **$15.00**

Comment: Skywalk observatory is permanently closed as of Spring 2020, so this is no longer an option. A new observation area may reopen in the future, but is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 7):

The Prudential center is a great place to see it. Directly above the observatory is the bar [Top of the Hub](http://www.topofthehub.net/)
You can go up without any charge and buy a drink at the bar and walk around and enjoy the views.

Here's a picture I quickly snapped on my phone from last year at the Top of the Hub bar:
[image]

Comment: Top of the Hub is also permanently closed as of Spring 2020, so this isn't an option anymore either.